# Building a back button into my application and storing edittext fields

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 views in my app. A form input and a screen to review the form data and confirm. The user inputs the data on the form submission screen in edittext fields. When the user clicks submit, they are presented with the data they input and a 'back' and 'confirm' button. I want it so that if the user presses back, they are returned to the form input screen and the data they input should still be in the editText fields.

At the moment, I am using an onClickListener to point to the form submission screen but the forms are all blank. How do I keep the data in them?

This is the onClickListener:

```
bBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent j = new Intent(FormConfirm.this, FormCreate.class);
            startActivity(j);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please view the Activity lifecycle in the Android Activity documentation.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html You need to save the values using, e.g. SharedPreferences.

Comment: SharedPreferences works and also you can use static variables and set the text to the edit text in the onResume() of the first activity with the values in the static variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated you should save the values somehow, for example by using SharedPreferences.

As an example, when you go from the `Input`-form Activity to the `Submit`-form Activity:

```
bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent j = new Intent(FormCreate.this, FormSubmit.class);
        saveInput();
        startActivity(j);
    }
});
```

Where the method `saveInput()` could look something like:

```
private void saveInput() {
    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.someId);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    preferences.edit().putString("input",input.getText().toString()).commit();   
}
```

And then, when you press back, the back action could simply be something like:

```
bBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FormConfirm.this.finish();
    }
});
```

That will cause the current activity to exit and your previous activity will be visible. If you want to display the last saved input when the `Input`-form Activity starts, you can simply do something like this:

```
private void loadInput(){
    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.someId);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String savedText = getString("input", "default input text");
    input.setText(savedText);   
}
```

and call that method in the `onCreate`-method in your  `Input`-form Activity.

Comment: This is most likely the right answer, but its a lot more complicated than my ability right now. I'm just learning android so this kind of thing will be useful when I get better at it. Thanks for the good input

Comment: I'm just glad to help. Just remember this post if you in the future need anything similar ;)

Answer (score 2):

i don't know how to write code on android apps, but i think, why you not to store them into variable flag and call them on edit text field?
for example, if you already fill the form and click submit, you can make a function for store data first on variable flag and show the data in form submission, so when you click back button, you can call the value that you store on variable flag into edittext.

i hope my answer can give you some inspiration

Answer (score 1):

Had an inspiration and found a workaround that might not necessarily be correct but it works :) just changed the Java code for the activity to the following:

```
bBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I know that finish() brings you back to the main activity but it works quite well for my needs right now

Comment: That's not quite correct. `finish()` takes you back to whoever launched the Activity where `finish()` is called. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()